# Energy configuration of a set of charges

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, electric-current

I want to understand why a set of charges seek the minimum energy configuration, especially inside a conductor. This is really intuitive, but I would welcome a more rigorous approach.
My question comes from studying what happens when you put together 2 conductors of different dimensions, with different charges, through a conducting wire. I know that in electrostatics the tangential component of the electric field is zero because otherwise charges would be moving around the surface of the conductor system, but what I fail to understand rigorously (intuitively it's clear) is why charges cannot keep moving in the conductor surface indefinitely : why the steady state implies no charge movement

Comment: Electrostatics contains statics so no currents. More seriously permanent currents are prevented by energy dissipation by Joule effect. They however exist in superconductors (and other "exotic" systems) which don't comply with Ohm law.

Comment: Yes but how are we sure that charge will eventually stop moving (assume there is no resistance) ?